# Short sci-fi story: aliens regret setting Earth's destruction in motion

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens, hard-sci-fi

The story is basically told from an alien's point of view. Essentially they observed us from far off, deemed us as violent and a danger to the universe, and set course (asteroid or something) to kill us. They kept observing and saw all the art and beauty we created and realized we were actually not so bad, but by then they couldn't stop it. So it was sort of also an apology letter to Earth in the end.

First read it like a year ago online and I can't find any trace of it anymore, nor can I recall the site it was on. Anyone know what short story this is?

Comment: You should delete either this question or [this other](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/76904/32339). If it wasn't because currently none have up voted nor accepted answers, they would be duplicates.

Comment: @Deion looks like StorySeeker originally posted this question (the other one) under an unregistred account and only later properly registered.

Comment: @Deion Trish has the right of it, I even edited the other topic (using this acct) to reflect that but it looks like my edit isn't 'acceptable'? I can't delete it, so what would you have me do? In fact I explained the issue and you yourself it wasn't acceptable. I'm dead new to the site and it's already proving irrational in how it functions :/ I'm not trying to be rude, just frustrated.

Comment: @Kevin You should probably mark [the other version of this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76904/short-sci-fi-story-aliens-regret-destroying-earth-with-asteroid-or-something) as the duplicate, seeing as that is the one posted with the OP's unregistered account and which he probably cannot access anymore, seeing as Storyteller accepted my answer on this question. I posted my answer on the older/other question first before I looked into things, and realizing this version is the one posted with a registered account, concluded that OP may only be able to access this version.

Comment: @TrishLing Fixed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think I found it, though the original author remains anonymous, and even the title is a mystery, as it is referred to as["The Gift](http://www.creepypasta.com/the-gift-of-mercy/) [of Mercy"](http://girlchik.com/2008/12/17/the-gift-of-mercy-by-anonymous/) or ["We Know You Are Out There"](http://www.reddit.com/r/Frisson/comments/1sen20/text_we_know_you_are_out_there_short_story_about/) and even ["We Made a Mistake"](http://www.ar15.com/archive/topic.html?b=1&f=5&t=980867).

It's origins are mysterious, but it's been posted on many message boards and creepypasta sites. As far as I can discern from discussions about the story, it's origin thread is [here on 4Chan](http://suptg.thisisnotatrueending.com/archive/2911901/), titled "We Made a Mistake". What's more, there's a Part 2 and 3 posted there as well.

Full Text:

> !MESSAGE BEGINS
>
> We made a mistake. That is the simple, undeniable truth of the matter, however painful it might be. The flaw was not in our
>   Observatories, for those machines were as perfect as we could make,
>   and they showed us only the unfiltered light of truth. The flaw was
>   not in the Predictor, for it is a device of pure, infallible logic,
>   turning raw data into meaningful information without the taint of
>   emotion or bias. No, the flaw was within us, the Orchestrators of this
>   disaster, the sentients who thought themselves beyond such failings.
>   We are responsible.
>
> It began a short while ago, as these things are measured, less than 6^6 Deeli ago, though I suspect our systems of measure will mean
>   very little by the time anyone receives this transmission. We detected
>   faint radio signals from a blossoming intelligence 2^14 Deelis outward
>   from the Galactic Core, as photons travel. At first crude and
>   unstructured, these leaking broadcasts quickly grew in complexity and
>   strength, as did the messages they carried. Through our Observatories
>   we watched a world of strife and violence, populated by a barbaric
>   race of short-lived, fast breeding vermin. They were brutal and
>   uncultured things which stabbed and shot and burned each other with no
>   regard for life or purpose. Even their concepts of Art spoke of
>   conflict and pain. They divided themselves according to some bizarre
>   cultural patterns and set their every industry to cause of death.
>
> They terrified us, but we were older and wiser and so very far away, so we did not fret. Then we watched them split the atom and
>   breach the heavens within the breadth of one of their single, short
>   generations, and we began to worry. When they began actively
>   transmitting messages and greetings into space, we felt fear and
>   horror. Their transmissions promised peace and camaraderie to any who
>   were listening, but we had watched them for too long to buy into such
>   transparent deceptions. They knew we were out here, and they were
>   coming for us.
>
> The Orchestrators consulted the Predictor, and the output was dire. They would multiply and grow and flood out of their home system
>   like some uncountable tide of Devourer worms, consuming all that lay
>   in their path. It might take 6^8 Deelis, but they would destroy us if
>   left unchecked. With aching carapaces we decided to act, and sealed
>   our fate.
>
> The Gift of Mercy was 8^4 strides long with a mouth 2/4 that in diameter, filled with many 4^4 weights of machinery, fuel, and
>   ballast. It would push itself up to 2/8th of light speed with its
>   onboard fuel, and then begin to consume interstellar Primary Element
>   2/2 to feed its unlimited acceleration. It would be traveling at
>   nearly light speed when it hit. They would never see it coming. Its
>   launch was a day of mourning, celebration, and reflection. The horror
>   of the act we had committed weighted heavily upon us all; the
>   necessity of our crime did little to comfort us.
>
> The Gift had barely cleared the outer cometary halo when the mistake was realized, but it was too late. The Gift could not be
>   caught, could not be recalled or diverted from its path. The
>   architects and work crews, horrified at the awful power of the thing
>   upon which they labored, had quietly self-terminated in droves,
>   walking unshielded into radiation zones, neglecting proper null
>   pressure safety or simple ceasing their nutrient consumption until
>   their metabolic functions stopped. The appalling cost in lives had
>   forced the Ochestrators to streamline the Gift’s design and
>   construction. There had been no time for the design or implementation
>   of anything beyond the simple, massive engines and the stabilizing
>   systems. We could only watch in shame and horror as the light of
>   genocide faded into infrared against the distant void.
>
> They grew, and they changed, in a handful of lifetimes they abolished war, abandoned their violent tendencies and turned
>   themselves to the grand purposes of life and Art. We watched them
>   remake first themselves, and then their world. Their frail, soft
>   bodies gave way to gleaming metals and plastics, they unified their
>   people through an omnipresent communications grid and produced Art of
>   such power and emotion, the likes of which the Galaxy has never seen
>   before. Or again, because of us.
>
> They converted their home world into a paradise (by their standards) and many 10^6s of them poured out into the surrounding
>   system with a rapidity and vigor that we could only envy. With bodies
>   built to survive every environment from the day lit surface of their
>   innermost world, to the atmosphere of their largest gas giant and the
>   cold void in-between, they set out to sculpt their system into
>   something beautiful. At first we thought them simple miners, stripping
>   the rocky planets and moons for vital resources, but then we began to
>   see the purpose to their constructions, the artworks carved into every
>   surface, and traced across the system in glittering lights and dancing
>   fusion trails. And still, our terrible Gift approached.
>
> They had less than 2^2 Deeli to see it, following so closely on the tail of its own light. In that time, oh so brief even by their
>   fleeting lives, more than 10^10 sentients prepared for death. Lovers
>   exchanged last words, separated by worlds and the tyranny of light
>   speed. Their planet side engineers worked frantically to build
>   sufficient transmission infrastructure to upload the countless masses
>   with the necessary neural modifications, while those above dumped
>   lifetimes of music and literature from their databanks to make room
>   for passengers. Those lacking the required hardware or the time to
>   acquire it consigned themselves to death, lashed out in fear and pain,
>   or simply went about their lives as best they could under the
>   circumstances.
>
> The Gift arrived suddenly, the light of its impact visible in our skies, shining bright and cruel even to the unaugmented ocular
>   receptor. We watched and we wept for our victims, dead so many Deelis
>   before the light of their doom had even reached us. Many 6^4s of those
>   who had been directly or even tangentially involved in the creation of
>   the Gift sealed their spiracles with paste as a final penance for the
>   small roles they had played in this atrocity. The light dimmed, the
>   dust cleared, and our Observatories refocused upon the place where
>   their shining blue world had once hung in the void, and found only
>   dust and the pale gleam of an orphaned moon, wrapped in a thin,
>   burning wisp of atmosphere that had once belonged to its parent.
>
> Radiation and relativistic shrapnel had wiped out much of the inner system, and continent sized chunks of molten rock carried
>   screaming ghosts outward at interstellar escape velocities, damned to
>   wander the great void for an eternity. The damage was apocalyptic, but
>   not complete, from the shadows of the outer worlds, tiny points of
>   light emerged, thousands of fusion trails of single ships and world
>   ships and everything in between, many 10^6s of survivors in flesh and
>   steel and memory banks, ready to rebuild. For a few moments we felt
>   relief, even joy, and we were filled with the hope that their culture
>   and Art would survive the terrible blow we had dealt them. Then came
>   the message, tightly focused at our star, transmitted simultaneously
>   by hundreds of their ships.
>
> “We know you are out there, and we are coming for you.”
>
> !MESSAGE ENDS

Comment: You are awesome! It looks a little different than I remember but this is it!