# Short story where aliens are observing humans then attack

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a story where it's being told from the "alien's" perspective about them observing Earth in its primitive times via telescopes from systems away.

They see us at our worst with war, violence and decide that we need to be purged for the good of the universe or something.

As the missiles are flying they keep observing and see us mature compassion and stuff but it's too late to stop the attack.

The attack hits and then they receive a message from Earth saying we're coming for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [Short sci-fi story: aliens regret setting Earth's destruction in motion](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76923/short-sci-fi-story-aliens-regret-setting-earths-destruction-in-motion/76938#76938), this story has many names.

> It's origins are mysterious, but it's been posted on many message boards and creepypasta sites. As far as I can discern from discussions about the story, it's origin thread is [here](http://suptg.thisisnotatrueending.com/archive/2911901/) on 4Chan, titled "We Made a Mistake". What's more, there's a Part 2 and 3 posted there as well.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure what to search for!

Comment: No worries. Even knowing it existed, it took me three searches. :-D

Comment: I'm curious, do you know where the other 2 parts can be found?

Comment: @Ovaryraptor: Search the 4Chan thread for "No.2917914".